# Need to convert word month into number from a table

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I would like to convert the column df['Date'] to numeric time format:
the current format i.e. Oct 9, 2019 --> 10-09-2019
Here is my code but I did not get an error until printing it. Thanks for your support!

I made some changes, 
I want to convert the current time format to numeric time format, ie: Oct 9, 2019 --> 10-09-2019 in a column of a table

```
from time import strptime

strptime('Feb','%b').tm_mon


Date_list = df['Date'].tolist()
Date_num = []
for i in Date_list:
    num_i=strptime('[i[0:3]]', '%b').tm_mon
    Date_num.append(num_i)
df['Date'] = Date_num 
print(df['Date'])
```

### I got the error message as follows:

KeyError
ValueError: time data '[i[0:3]]' does not match format '%b'

```
Date
Oct 09, 2019
Oct 08, 2019
Oct 07, 2019
Oct 04, 2019
Oct 03, 2019
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.  Your posted code crashes because `df` is undefined.

Comment: The error is telling you that the key you gave, `i[0:3]`, is not in the dict.  Since you failed to provide the data frame or any program trace, we can't give you much help.

Comment: Use [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), do not convert to a list and do not iterate! I would suggest leaving it as a datetime object rather than converting back to a string. Note you need to specify the `format` argument. Use [this page](http://strftime.org/) as a reference to figure out what the `format` string should be in your case. As a hint, leave the spaces and the comma in the formatting string exactly as they appear in your date strings.

Comment: What @Dan said. But you also seem to be confusing passing the actual literal string "[i[0:3]]" into strptime, vs the value of `'[i[0:3]]'`.

Answer (score 1):

assuming `Date` column in `df` is of str/object type. 
can be validated by running `pd.dtypes`. 
in such case you can convert your column directly to `datetime` type by

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

which will show you dates in default format of `2019-10-09`. If you want you can convert this to any other date format you want very easily by doing something like

```
pd.dt.dt.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
```

please go through https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html for more info related to pandas datetime functions/operations

Comment: Thank you so much, all workable! the problem is solved.